# How can I send a text message/SMS with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [any good php tutorial on how to send sms to phones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022597/any-good-php-tutorial-on-how-to-send-sms-to-phones)

I'm trying to figure out how I can send text messages/SMS messages with PHP to phones. Is there a way to do this without having to pay for some service? Also can I make a way for people to respond to texts/SMS? For instance when they receive the message can they respond and that data be stored in a MySQL table or something?

Comment: Massive number of dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sms+gateway+php

Comment: If your in need of a list of carriers for your mysql database I have made a git repo here: https://github.com/snowballrandom/email_sms_phone_gateways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send an email in the format of the user's carrier, using formats listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways).

If you'd like to receive messages back and process them with business rules, you'd need to pay for an SMS gateway. Not sure where you are located, but I've asked a similar question on finding a decent Canadian provider [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922356/advice-on-a-canadian-sms-gateway-provider).

Comment: is there any such list for countries outside US?